# Can't get date from NSDateFormatter with date 2012-11-21 03:57:39-04

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, nsdateformatter, date-formatting

I get a date 2012-11-21 03:57:39-04 and I can't get an NSDate from it. I use the yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:sszz format. I guess I'm stuck with the time zone part. I've tried different kinds of 'Z' and 'z' types but still can't get it.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:sszz"]; // "2012-11-21 03:57:39-04"
```

Comment: Share the code you are using

Comment: i've updated my question with code

Comment: Can you add the rest of your code for the NSDate formatting?

Comment: Your edit was rolled back, because it's inappropriate. If you want to post the answer you found yourself, do it properly by writing an answer in the space provided below. Answering your own question is acceptable here, as you can see in [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). You must do it properly, though, and write a complete answer that will  help others in the future. You'll be held to the same standards as the others who answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

The z-Codes doesn't fit, because they always requires minutes. Try a single `X` or `x` instead.

http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

```
X 1 -08
    +0530
    Z     The ISO8601 basic format with hours field and optional minutes field. The ISO8601 UTC indicator "Z" is used when local time offset is 0. (The same as x, plus "Z".)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just append @"00" and you should be fine

```
  NSString *dateStr = [@"2012-11-21 03:57:39-04" stringByAppendingString:@"00"];

  NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  NSLocale *en_US_POSIXLocale =
  [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
  [dateFormat setLocale:en_US_POSIXLocale];
  [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"];
  NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this format:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:sszzz"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. The format wasn't the problem because the above format @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:sszz" did actually work. Sorry for disturbing.

Answer (score -1):

**answer posted by the OP Iryna Tsimokhautsava**

> I found the error. The format wasn't the problem because the above
>   format @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:sszz" did actually work. Sorry for
>   disturbing.

Comment: If you're going to do it this way, you should at least make your answer CW. The proper way (IMO) is simply to leave a comment to the OP explaining that you rolled back their edit and that they can post a self-answer if they'd like (and link them to the help center).